# How to make a full page JS and CSS menu

Tags: javascript, css, html, menu

To be more specific, how do we create a JavaScript menu with CSS styling that occupies the whole page, but the menu bar will be shown. There will be an icon on the top-left. Upon clicking that icon or symbol, the menu should appear and that image should glow. And after cliking it again, the menu goes away. I tried a lot but failed. I am just 14 year old. Please help me.

If there is something like that already which is open source, please post a link so that I can get on it.

**UPDATE:** I did it own my own.

Comment: Show your best attempt and we will help you.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using or do you have knowledge on a JS framework (jQuery, Mootools?) to accomplish the result? Can you provide a working example (jsFiddle)?

Comment: i suggest you take some books on CSS and JS and start reading them...or tutorials too will be good...I am 16 and learned a lot simply by reading books...

Comment: You say you unsuccessfully tried, but you didn't show what you tried. My crystal ball isn't working today so you'll need to show the code and describe the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this site [here](http://apycom.com/) which gives you different menu bars to choose from. all you need to do is download a menu and change the menu details inside the script so that you can change menu names, add more or fewer menu tabs, etc. It uses jquery and contains its own css page which you can manipulate.

In order to hide and show the menu, how about using something like a html tooltip, except for hovering over the button to open/hide the menu, you can set it so that if you click the button, it opens/hide the button ?

Comment: @Rishikesh its not opensource u need to buy the paid version from apycom.com  .

Answer (score 0):

Try this its opensource

http://www.interspire.com/content/2005/12/07/building-an-expanding-dhtml-menu-with-css-and-javascript/

http://www.noupe.com/css/13-awesome-java-script-css-menu.html

Comment: Thanks guys. But I tried and did it on my own. Thanks for you.